# Concatenating Singly Linked Lists Into One List

Tags: java, singly-linked-list

```
    package singlyLinkedList;
```

`import net.datastructures.*;

// CREATE LIST 1
// CREATE LIST 2
// PRINT LISTS 1 & 2
// CONCATENATE LISTS 1 & 2 into LIST 3
// PRINT LIST 3
public class GameEntrySinglyLinkedList {

    public static SinglyLinkedList<String> concatenate (SinglyLinkedList<String>game1, SinglyLinkedList<String>game2) {
        // DECLARE METHOD LISTS
        SinglyLinkedList<String> result;
        SinglyLinkedList<String> temp;

        // TRY
        try {
            result = game1.clone();
            temp = game2.clone();
            /* DEBUGGING PURPOSES
            System.out.printf ("\n\n(DEBUG) Test Result: %s\n", result);
            System.out.printf ("\n\n(DEBUG) Test Temp: %s\n", temp);
            */
        }
        // CATCH CLONE EXCEPTION
        catch(CloneNotSupportedException n) {
            return null; 
        }
        // WHILE
        while(!temp.isEmpty()) {
            result.addFirst(temp.removeFirst());
            /* DEBUGGING PURPOSES
            System.out.printf ("\n\n(DEBUG) Test Result: %s\n", result);
            System.out.printf ("\n\n(DEBUG) Test Temp: %s\n", temp);
            */
        }

        return result;
    }

    /* *********** *
     * MAIN METHOD *
     * *********** */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // LOCAL VARIABLES
        SinglyLinkedList<String> game1 = new SinglyLinkedList<String> ();
        SinglyLinkedList<String> game2 = new SinglyLinkedList<String> ();
        SinglyLinkedList<String> gameTotal = new SinglyLinkedList<String> ();

        // POPULATE LISTS
        game1.addFirst("CLG");
        game1.addFirst("C9");

        game2.addFirst("TSM");
        game2.addFirst("Immortals");

        // PRINT LISTS
        System.out.printf ("\n\nGame 1: %s\n", game1);
        System.out.printf ("\n\nGame 2: %s\n", game2);

        // CALL CONCATENATE METHOD, STORE IN gameTotal
        gameTotal = concatenate(game1, game2);

        // PRINT TOTAL GAMES LIST FROM gameTotal
        System.out.printf("\n\nAll Games: %s\n", gameTotal);

    }

}

/* Can't figure out why .addLast won't work but .addFirst will. 
 * It screws up the order a little in the final list as well as
 * an extra ", " after CLG which shows an empty spot in the list
 * at the end. Don't know how to get rid of that either. */`

I have made two linked lists and I need to populate a third list with those first two lists concatenated. I am stuck because I need to print out the third list, and my friends and I can't figure out how to make the concatenate function be used on the two lists to make a third one and print it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are adding all items using `addFirst`, and according to the question you just want to concatenate them (and not sort), I assume the result you are looking for is:

```
List 1: C9 -> CLG        
List 2: Immortals -> TSM
Expected result: C9 -> CLG -> Immortals -> TSM
```

So assuming that, the implementation can be:

```
public static SinglyLinkedList<String> concatenate (SinglyLinkedList<String>game1, SinglyLinkedList<String>game2) {
    SinglyLinkedList<String> result;
    SinglyLinkedList<String> temp;
    try {
        result = game1.clone(); // game1 copied into result
        temp = game2.clone(); // get copy of second list, which we will destroy in the process of concatenation
    }
    catch(CloneNotSupportedException e) { // can only happen if it was not implemented
        return null; 
    }
    while(!temp.isEmpty()) {
        result.addLast(temp.removeFirst());
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I will need to throw an exception for the .clone() though because its an unhandled exception.
Edit: Could I even re-create the same lists inside the concatenate function,  I know that would be pretty dumb though.

Comment: that exception will only happen if clone method was not implemented. So of course you need to know if it is implemented by the library you use (seems it is), but if it is, this exception will never happen. I added therefore a really primitive handling of that exception

Comment: Okay I understand all of this except the temp and result are not being resolved.

Comment: Did you define them _above_ try? What exactly the error it's giving you is?

Comment: Okay, the above code has no errors, let me try and get it to run now and see what happens.

Comment: EDIT: I will just edit my original code at the top and the output I received was only the portion of the first list. "All Games: (C9, CLG, )"

Comment: Okay, so I changed the .addLast to .addFirst and it then printed out everything. Only downside is there is an extra space at the end which happens after the cloning phase. "All Games: (TSM, Immortals, C9, CLG, )"

Answer (score 0):

You can do something by traversing game2 like:
basically start with game2's head and append it to game1.

You can add a method to your list like

```
public SinglyLinkedListNode getHead()
{
   return head;
}
```

and use it

```
public void concatenate(SinglyLinkedList game1, SinglyLinkedList game2) 
{

            SinglyLinkedListNode current = game2.getHead();
            while (current != null) 
           {

                  game1.addLast( current );
                  current = current.next;
            }

}
```

EDIT : I see you are using SinglyLinkedList.java from probably [here](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~mrmiller/15-121/Lectures/23/SinglyLinkedList.java)

This method will work by traversing, and hence you should treat this only as to know how to concatenate by traversing.

Comment: I receive an error to be SinglyLinkedListNode cannot be resolved to a type and also the field SinglyLinkedList.head is not visible.
Edit: Am I missing some declarations or imports?

Comment: You can add a getter for your head and use it.

Comment: I take back what I said, can you show your code for addFirst() method? You should be able to have a "next" field in your node in the list. I don't see how just a "String" can have that.

Comment: I don't understand how the first code 
public String getHead()
{
   return head;
} 
will help at all because it doesn't seem like the program knows what head even is.

Comment: This is all the code I have...there is no other code.
Edit: It outputs -  
Game 1: (C9, CLG)  
Game 2: (Immortals, TSM)

Comment: I am curious. Can you show your code for SinglyLinkedList.java?